# Mysql database selecting with relation

Tags: mysql, sql, select, relation

I have this table that I hold userlist for my msn application. There's another table for the friendship where it has two foreign keys from userlist.

user: id, name, online, ip...
friend: id1, id2

I want the information of the users that are friend with a specific id.

I'm using this sql query:

```
SELECT (latest_ip, email, online, pass, status) 
from im.user JOIN im.friend ON user.id = friend.id1 
WHERE user.id = 5
```

what am i missing?

Comment: Oh and the mysql error: Error code: 1241: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: you are missing some informations regarding your question, **(1)** what do you get when you execute the query? **(2)** can you show sample records with desired output?

Comment: Well the friend table contains the information about which id is friend with who. its like id 5 friend with id 12. The problem i see here is that id 5 might have more then one friend so the WHERE part contains more then one id. The thing i want to do is that check friend table for friends of id 5, get those id s and query them on user table to get the other information like name, latest ip etc.

Comment: I am also using this query that makes similar execution: SELECT (latest_ip, email, online, pass, status) from im.user WHERE user.id = (SELECT id2 from im.friend WHERE id1 = 5) but the problem is the same, second query might return more then one id

Answer (score 0):

remove the `parenthesis` on your select clause, *you don't need them*

```
SELECT latest_ip, email, online, pass, status
from   im.user 
       INNER JOIN im.friend 
           ON user.id = friend.id1 
WHERE user.id = 5
```

**UPDATE 1**

you need to have extra join with the table `user` again since you want to get the informations of the user's friends.

```
SELECT  c.*
from    im.user a
        INNER JOIN im.friend b
            ON a.id = b.id1 
        INNER JOIN im.user c
            ON b.id2 = c.id
WHERE   a.id = 5
```

Comment: Oh well. Thanks for the help. The first query that i wrote seems not working but the second one with the sub query seems working when i remove the paranthesis. Again, thanks for the help :)